# How do I use add_custom_command to build fortran library and get both .so and mod files?

Tags: cmake, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have a build process where I have a fortran library dependency that I am building using add_custom_command. This fortran library has its own Makefile and works fine for that. If  I build it manually using `make` it will produce the shared library and a bunch of .o and .mod files in a separate build directory, and then it moves the.so and .mod files to lib/. I need both the .so and the .mod files, but I have not determined how to get the .mod files when I do it this way in CMake. It works for the .so, but .mod files are somewhere in the nether.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${LIBDIR}/lib/myfortlib.so ${LIBDIR}/lib/myfortlib.mod COMMAND make WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBDIR})
add_custom_target(myfortlib DEPENDS ${LIBDIR}/lib/myfortlib.so)
```

If I were to build directly with cmake I can specify a `Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` but I really want to just use this libraries existing build process and not have to manage it.

Comment: So you're saying that when a sub-`make` is generated via a custom command, it behaves differently than when the same `make` command is run, with the same working directory, from the command line?  That sounds pretty surprising.  It might be worth your while to enable verbose output so as to monitor the exact commands being executed during the cmake-based build.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks... I went back to examine it more closely and found the problem. The .o files were not getting removed on cleans, although .so and .mod would be. When I would build it again, it could recreate the shared library using the existing .o files but would not generate new .mod files, so they could never be transferred to lib/ directory